# unable to install library from github using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, pip

I have forked [this repo](https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe). I'm trying to install this from my repo using `pip` since I have made some changes but its constantly failing. I tried few things but no luck:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/rshiva/python-boilerpipe.git#egg=python-boilerpipe
-e git://github.com:rshiva/python-boilerpipe.git#egg=python-boilerpipe
```

Error I get is

```
no matches found
```

Why do we have to mention egg ? What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I get a different error; running `setup.py` fails because the boilerpipe download fails to unzip.

Comment: In other words, your first `pip install` command is entirely correct. The package is downloaded and pip *tries* to install it, but it is that step that fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `pip` command-line is correct, but the *installation* fails.

That's because the repo contains a [broken copy of the `boilerplate-1.2.0-bin.tar.gz` file](https://github.com/rshiva/python-boilerpipe/blob/master/boilerpipe-1.2.0-bin.tar.gz). The `setup.py` script finds this file, will not download a fresh copy, but because the file is incomplete extracting that file fails:

```
Updating ./src/python-boilerpipe clone
Running setup.py (path:/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.4/src/python-boilerpipe/setup.py) egg_info for package python-boilerpipe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.4/src/python-boilerpipe/setup.py", line 27, in <module>
    download_jars(datapath=DATAPATH)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.4/src/python-boilerpipe/setup.py", line 22, in download_jars
    for tarinfo in tar.getmembers():
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py", line 1738, in getmembers
    self._load()        # all members, we first have to
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py", line 2311, in _load
    tarinfo = self.next()
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py", line 2246, in next
    self.fileobj.seek(self.offset)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/gzip.py", line 573, in seek
    self.read(1024)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/gzip.py", line 365, in read
    if not self._read(readsize):
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/gzip.py", line 449, in _read
    self._read_eof()
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/gzip.py", line 482, in _read_eof
    crc32, isize = struct.unpack("<II", self._read_exact(8))
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/gzip.py", line 286, in _read_exact
    raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

Remove this file from your repository, and your installation works just fine.

Comment: to clarify others, just comment out the statement: `download_jars(datapath=DATAPATH)`